# Hibernate: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have that nativeQuery query in my Repository.

```
    @Query(value = Constant.QUERY_FIND_GUIDE, nativeQuery=true)
List<Guide> findGuide(String locationName, String gender, String type, String language);
```

and Constant.QUERY_FIND_GUIDE is

```
public static final String QUERY_FIND_GUIDE = "SELECT g.id FROM Guide g " + 
        " LEFT JOIN g.user u  " + 
        " LEFT JOIN g.locations l " + 
        " LEFT JOIN g.languages lang "+
        "WHERE (UPPER(?1)=UPPER('NULL') OR ?1 IS NULL OR ?1 ='' OR l.locationName = ?1) "
        + " AND (UPPER(?2)=UPPER('NULL') OR ?2 IS NULL OR ?2 ='' OR g.gender =?2) "
        + " AND (?3 IS NULL OR ?3 ='' OR "
        + " (CASE WHEN UPPER(?3)=UPPER('NULL') THEN g.cardnumber IS NULL ELSE g.cardnumber IS NOT NULL END) )"
        + " AND (UPPER(?4)=UPPER('NULL') OR ?4 IS NULL OR ?4='' OR lang.language = ?4)";
```

When I run the page I get this error:

> 2018-04-24 03:05:32.198  WARN 1340 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
>   2018-04-24 03:05:32.198 ERROR 1340 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (UPPER('Ha Noi')=UPPER('NULL') OR 'Ha Noi' IS NULL OR 'Ha Noi' ='' at line 1
>   2018-04-24 03:05:32.208 ERROR 1340 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.w.tgo.controller.OperatorController    : 
>   error search: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

I try all solution on google but can't fix it. Can someone help me please?

Comment: You probably need an N in front of the Unicode text.

Comment: You have a SQL syntax error here: `AND (?3 IS NULL OR ?3 ='' OR "` this `OR "` is invalid, you have to test it with something even if it is `''=''`

Comment: Also, this `UPPER('NULL')` makes no sense. If your parameter is passing the **string** `NULL` or `null` you are already changing it to uppercase, no need to do it both sides so `UPPER(?whatever)='NULL'`

Comment: i try hard code locationName ="Ha Noi " but same error :(

Comment: @JorgeCampos i try this help but same error :  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (UPPER('Ha Noi ')='NULL' OR 'Ha Noi ' = NULL OR 'Ha Noi ' ='' OR l.locatio' at line 1

Comment: Yeah, was just looking at the conditions, it turns out that your JOINs are wrong you are missing the joining condition for all of then: `sometable t LEFT JOIN someOtherTable t2 ON t.someColumn = t2.someColumn`

Comment: @JorgeCampos this hibernate help JOIN if 2 table have relasionship. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Comment: You are using a Native Query `nativeQuery=true`, which requires native SQL code. Either fix the query or convert it to a hibernate query.

Comment: @JorgeCampos  I try convert it to hibernate query and it worked, thanks for help :D